# Is "not only - but just" similar to "not only - but also"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Context:

> We’ve become unsatisfied, wanting much more than we need, forgetting
> the days when it was not only acceptable to wear your mother’s or
> grandmother’s wedding dress, but just how things were done.

Which part does the phrase "but just how things were done" contrast with, "the days" or "acceptable"? Is "not only - but just" in this sentence similar to the structure "not only - but also"? If so, shouldn't what follows "but just" be an adjective so it'd be in parallel with "acceptable"?
How can you paraphrase this sentence without using "not only - but just"?

Comment: _Just_ doesn't belong with _but_ - 'just how things were done' means 'simply a common practice at that time'. It was not only acceptable, but usual to wear your mother's wedding dress.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's much clearer now.